# Issue with Express sessions and fs module

Tags: node.js, session, express, mkdir, fs

```
app.post('/register', express.BodyParser(), function (req, res){

   var newu = new UserModel({});

   newu.user = req.body.nuser;
   newu.pass = req.body.npass;
   newu.mail = req.body.nmail;

   var pathu = __dirname + '/users/' + req.body.nuser;

   newu.save(function (err, newu){

       req.session.user = new.user;

       if(err) throw err;

       fs.mkdir(pathu, function (err){

           if (err) throw err;

        });    

   });

   res.redirect('/home);

});
```

Always when the fs.mkdir is executed, I lose all the current Express' sessions, is there any way to execute fs.mkdir and keep all the Express' sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how it's causing your symptoms, but this line:

```
req.session.user = new.user;
```

should likely be:

```
req.session.user = newu.user;
```

**UPDATE**

The root of the problem is that creating the directory is triggering nodemon to restart the app and the default in-memory session store loses all sessions when that occurs.  The fix is to use a persistent session store like [Redis](http://redis.io/) via [connect-redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis).

Comment: True! But it still isn't working. I'm going to try Connect, I guess it works better with sessions than Express.

Comment: @user1913693 Express uses Connect for sessions so I don't think you'll see much difference!  One other problem I see is that you probably shouldn't be redirecting to `/home` until after the `fs.mkdir` callback is called.

Comment: That's what I want, but, I start this app.js, and when fs.mkdir is executed, nodemon sais "restarting due to changes", maybe that's the problem, fs.mkdir restarts the node.js server, so when that happends, I lose the current sessions.

Comment: @user1913693 Ah, no wonder.  Put your sessions in a persistent store like [Redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis) instead of the default memory store.

Comment: Sorry, but I was looking some tutorials of Redis with node.js and keeping sessions, and none works :S Do you know a good tutorial for keep sessions in node.js even using the fs module?